# Using Tensorflow for Tic-Tac-Toe AI

Tags: tensorflow

**TLDR at bottom
I have been searching for days and the chances are I just don't know what to google since I'm very new to machine learning. After doing research I've decided that tensorflow is a good starting point (I'm open to other suggestions). When I looked for examples of tensorflow they all required a large repository of data to feed into the program, but I'm more interested in creating AI that learns while it plays a game, such as Tic Tac Toe. I'm having difficulty figuring out how to do this. Any advice helps, thanks!

TLDR: Are there any good, simple examples of a machine learning program (preferably tensorflow) that can help me make a Tic-Tac-Toe AI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also just started to learn more about machine learning, and it looks like the tutorial and library depend on the kind of machine learning you wish to pursue.
As you probably know there is supervised and unsupervised learning and reinforcement learning.

If you are curious about supervised and unsupervised learning, Tensorflow and SciKit Learn are the way to go.

If it's reinforcement learning, then openAI Gym would work best.

Here are some links to some tic-tac-toe repositories for each three.
Good Luck!

**Supervised and Unsupervised Learning**

https://github.com/3cky/tensorflow-rl-tictactoe (TensorFlow)

https://github.com/akapoorx00/tic-tac-toe-ml-project (SciKit Learn)

**Reinforcement Learning**

https://github.com/haje01/gym-tictactoe

https://gym.openai.com/docs/

Comment: I had heard those words before in articles/videos but never really understood them. It looks like i'll need to look into reinforcement learning, thank you so much for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

A quick search brought these up:

https://github.com/jamesq9/Tic-Tac-Toe-Machine-Learning-Using-Reinforcement-Learning
https://github.com/3cky/tensorflow-rl-tictactoe